# Making sort links on views better exposed filters toggle

Tags: views

I was able to create sort links on views using better exposed filters. I configured the sort filter sin such a way so I have one link that is ascending and another one descending, based on post date. This works very well. What would be amazing is if I could have one link that toggles achieving the behavior of the previously explained sort links. So for example when  I'm first looking at the view sorted by ascending date I would get one exposed sort link that would sort by descending (most recent ↓). Then when I would be looking at the view sorted by descending date I would only get one exposed sort link that would sort by ascending (most recent ↑).

So in conclusion I want to combine the two views sort links that I have: **most recent asc** and **most recent desc** into one link that toggles between **most recent ↑** and **most recent ↓**

Is there a way to do this with jQuery for example?

Comment: Weird, I can't add a bounty to this question

Comment: A question has to be open for 48 hours before a bounty can be added. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, BEF doesn't have a lot of extra classes or IDs that would facilitate this. You could post a feature request in the BEF issue queue requesting the necessary additional markup that would make this fairly simple using jQuery.

At a minimum, you'd need some sort of "active" designation so you knew which link reflected the current sort options.  Currently the active sort option is displayed as plain text (rather than a link) but there's an [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1188056) requesting the active sort be displayed as a link.

However, I should point out that I'll be out of town most of Aug and wont' be on the issue queue much... (I'm the BEF maintainer).

I'm always open to bounties!  :)

Comment: My co-worker @marvil07 made a a patch to have this functionality :) http://drupal.org/node/1240238